# How to change the "Weight" text to "Shipping Weight" in additional information component on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This is my additional information component, and i want to change the "Weight" text to "Shipping Weight" text. Btw, i also used woocommerce, Thank you everyone.

[additional-information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxt17.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `woocommerce_display_product_attributes` filter hook. try below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function change_woocommerce_display_product_attributes_label( $product_attributes, $product ){
    if( isset( $product_attributes['weight'] ) ){
        $product_attributes['weight']['label'] = __( 'Shipping Weight', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'change_woocommerce_display_product_attributes_label', 10, 2 );
```

**Tested and works.**

[image]